# Insert Geometry to PostGIS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, postgis, arcgis-js-api

Hi i am using postgresql and node.js for backend.
I want to insert point into database from frontend but i got error
"**value too long for type character varying(50)**"
This insert query i am using

```
insert into public.fat (name,splitter, geom) 
values ($1, $2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT($3)'))", [name,geom])
```

Following is frontend code of ArcGIS API to add point to database

```js
      var point = {
        type: "point", 
        longitude: -49.97,
        latitude: 41.73
      };

      var markerSymbol = {
        type: "simple-marker", 
        color: [226, 119, 40],
        outline: {

          color: [255, 255, 255],
          width: 2
        }
      };

      var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,

        });

      async function postData(url = 'http://localhost:8080/post', data = {name:'rafy', geom:point}) {

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        mode: 'cors', 
        cache: 'no-cache', 
        credentials: 'same-origin', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'

        },
```

Comment: you have only specified 2 values for the 3 fields

Answer (score 1):

You get an error when you have character limitation in the column structure you want to insert.
You must increase the character limit of the column in the table or the error in which variable occurs  $1::character varying(50)

Comment: Yes i have solved this issue but another issue is rising when i insert line feature. Error: 
somwthing wrong happend error: parse error - invalid geometry

Comment: I want to insert geoJSON to geom field

Comment: Your Geojson data similar to : {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[]} . Can u share your geometry data ?

Comment: "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      67.0612366034593,
      24.8376385526043
     ],
     [
      67.0612080853776,
      24.8376448361452
     ],
     [
      67.0611368605243,
      24.8377801811715
     ]
    
     
     [
      67.0608015003084,
      24.8384174513976
     ],
     [
      67.060515944476,
      24.8389600829249
     ]
   
   }

Comment: Apperently json is not valid . if your column geometry type u must casting like that ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 67.0612366034593, 24.8376385526043 ], [ 67.0612080853776, 24.8376448361452 ], [ 67.0611368605243, 24.8377801811715 ], [ 67.0608015003084, 24.8384174513976 ], [ 67.060515944476, 24.8389600829249 ]] }'::text)